# Add Delta Lake packages to AWS EMR Notebook

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-emr, delta-lake

Delta jar`delta-core_2.11-0.6.1.jar` is added to EMR Master node "SPARK_HOME/jars" directory. However calling Delta API from EMR Notebook I am getting following error:

```py
# Though Notebook comes with default SPARK instant so following line I didn't execute 
# spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp") \
#    .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.11:0.6.1") \
#    .getOrCreate()

from delta.tables import * # ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'delta'
```

CLI command `pyspark --packages "io.delta:delta-core_2.11:0.6.1"` is working fine in Master node. I am able to access Delta APIs in CLI mode.

Is there any way I can use Delta APIs directly in Notebook. Please suggest.

Comment: One of the way
```python
sc = spark.sparkContext
sc.addPyFile(/usr/lib/spark/jars/delta-core_2.11-0.6.1.jar")
from delta.tables import *  # working fine now
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tables.py file containing the DeltaTable class can be found in the delta repo on github.
You can find it here - https://github.com/delta-io/delta/tree/master/python/delta

You can either clone the repo (Remember to select the correct branch) or copy the file and upload that to Jupyter.  Either way it'll need adding as a dependency, so you'll need something like

```
import sys
sys.path.append('mnt/jupyterhome/<username>/<folder_containing_tables.py>)
```

Hopefully that'll get you up and running!